# sql spatial data gives wrong answer

Tags: sql, spatial

I really don't know what to do..

```
DECLARE @g geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 1))',4326)
DECLARE @g2 geography =geography::STGeomFromText( 'POLYGON((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0))',4326)
Declare @union  geography  =  @g2.STUnion(@g)   
Declare @diff  geography  =  @g2.STDifference(@g)   

SELECT @g.STArea() + @g2.STArea() - @union.STArea()

SELECT  @union.STArea()+@diff.STArea()
```

ret: "12306061878,1564"
     "123060620496,501"
Find 5 differences...

additional:

```
 select @union.ToString()
```

ret

```
POLYGON ((0 2, 0 0, 2 0, 2.0000000000000591 1.0001522971041397, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1.0000000000000655 2.0003044086154023, 0 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. My guess is that you're probably expecting the results provided by using `Geometry` instead of `Geography`:

```
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 1))',4326)
DECLARE @g2 geometry =geometry::STGeomFromText( 'POLYGON((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0))',4326)
Declare @union  geometry  =  @g2.STUnion(@g)   
Declare @diff  geometry  =  @g2.STDifference(@g)   

SELECT @g.STArea() + @g2.STArea() - @union.STArea()    
SELECT  @union.STArea()+@diff.STArea()
select @union.ToString()
```

returns:

```
POLYGON ((0 0, 2 0, 2 1, 3 1, 3 3, 1 3, 1 2, 0 2, 0 0))
```

Comment: one way to calc area of 2 polygons: @g.STArea() + @g2.STArea() - @union.STArea(), second - @union.STArea()+@diff.STArea(), why did it return different value?